# show text in central of paths SVG

Tags: svg, path

I have to display the text that centers in the SVG paths. Here is the SVG path:

```
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="M 12.07137,236.59885 H 85.706728 V 262.5523 H 34.403405 v 59.75328 H 11.467802 Z"
     id="no1"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <text
     id="text6">
      12.20%
    </text>
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 85.706728,236.59885 h 12.07137 v 51.30333 h 70.013942 v 12.67494 H 71.221083 v 48.88904 H 11.467802 V 322.30558 H 34.403405 V 262.5523 h 51.303323 z"
     id="no2"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <text
     id="text9">
      12.20%
    </text>
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 97.778098,236.59885 h 71.221082 l -1.20714,51.30333 H 97.778098 Z"
     id="no3"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <text
     id="text12">
      12.20%
    </text>
```

I got js code to display text by get x, y of path then calculate the x,y of text by x,y of path(but it seems not correct):

```
  var paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
   for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var path = paths[i]; // path element
    var text = path.nextElementSibling; // text element
    if(text && text.nodeName === 'text') {
      var new_x = document.createAttribute("x"); 
      new_x.value = path.getBBox().width / 2 + path.getBBox().x - text.getBBox().width / 2; 
      text.setAttributeNode(new_x);

      var new_y = document.createAttribute("y");
      new_y.value = path.getBBox().y + path.getBBox().height / 2 + text.getBBox().height / 3;
      text.setAttributeNode(new_y);
    }
  }
});
```

In the attached image, the red zone seems correct, but the yellow zone and blue zone seems is not correct. So can anyone please help to tell me how to calculate the value X, Y of text more correctly?
[image]

Comment: Define more correctly and create an algorithm that implements "more correctly". The shapes are not rectangles so their centre is not necessarily within the shape itself.

Comment: You are calculating the center of the bounding box of the path.   [The bounding box (or "bbox") of an element is the tightest fitting *rectangle* aligned with the axes of that element's user coordinate system that entirely encloses it and its descendants](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#BoundingBox)  The red path fills completely the bounding box. That's why "the red zone seems correct" However the the blue path has holes and you won't get the desired result.